# MultiHeadAttention giving very different values between versions (Pytorch/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

I'm trying to recreate a transformer that was written in Pytorch and make it Tensorflow. Everything was going pretty well until each version of MultiHeadAttention started giving extremely different outputs. Both methods are an implementation of multi-headed attention as described in the paper "Attention is all you Need", so they should be able to achieve the same output.

I'm converting

```
self_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(dModel, nheads, dropout=dropout)
```

to

```
self_attn = MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=nheads, key_dim=dModel, dropout=dropout)
```

For my tests, dropout is 0.

I'm calling them with:

```
self_attn(x,x,x)
```

where x is a tensor with shape=(10, 128, 50)

As expected from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html), the Pytorch version returns a tuple, (the target sequence length, embedding dimension), both with dimensions [10, 128, 50].

I'm having trouble getting the TensorFlow version to do the same thing. With Tensorflow I only get one tensor back, (size [10, 128, 50]) and it looks like neither the target sequence length or embedding dimension tensor from pytorch.
Based on the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention) I should be getting something comparable.

How can I get them to operate the same way? I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with Tensorflow but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nn.MultiheadAttention` outputs by default tuple with two tensors:

- `attn_output` -- result of self-attention operation
- `attn_output_weights` -- attention weights averaged(**!**) over heads

At the same time `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` outputs by default only one tensor `attention_output` (which corresponds to `attn_output` of pytorch). Attention weights of all heads also will be returned if parameter `return_attention_scores` is set to `True`, like:

```
output, scores = self_attn(x, x, x, return_attention_scores=True)
```

Tensor `scores` also should be averaged to achieve full correspondence with pytorch:

```
scores = tf.math.reduce_mean(scores, 1)
```

While rewriting keep in mind that by default (as in snippet in question) `nn.MultiheadAttention` expects input in form `(seq_length, batch_size, embed_dim)`, but `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` expects it in form `(batch_size, seq_length, embed_dim)`.

Comment: I'm getting the attention scores, but both (output, scores) aren't correct. 
The value for x is the same in all three spaces and they're both the same for the Tensorflow and Pytorch versions (albeit with a different number of decimal places)
I tried changing the input form like you said, which seems to have helped get the scores to be a little more similar though. 
I'm also not using dropout, but still seeing a large degree of randomness/variance in the tensorflow results. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: To help illustrate the problem better I made a similar post, but this time I made a short code snippet showing what I'm doing. I appreciate your help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919267/trying-to-achieve-same-result-with-pytorch-and-tensorflow-multiheadattention