# Trying to achieve same result with Pytorch and Tensorflow MultiheadAttention

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, attention-model

I'm trying to recreate a transformer written in Pytorch and implement it in Tensorflow. The problem is that despite both the documentation for the [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html) version and [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention) version, they still come out pretty differently.
I wrote a little code snippet to show the issue:

```
import torch
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class TransformerLayer(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, nhead, dropout=0):
        super(TransformerLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn = torch.nn.MultiheadAttention(d_model, nhead, dropout=dropout)

batch_size = 2
seq_length = 5
d_model = 10

src = np.random.uniform(size=(batch_size, seq_length, d_model))
srcTF = tf.convert_to_tensor(src)
srcPT = torch.Tensor(src.reshape((seq_length, batch_size, d_model)))

self_attnTF = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(key_dim=10, num_heads=5, dropout=0)
transformer_encoder = TransformerLayer(d_model=10, nhead=5, dropout=0.0)

output, scores = self_attnTF(srcTF, srcTF, srcTF, return_attention_scores=True)
print("Tensorflow Attendtion outputs:", output)
print("Tensorflow (averaged) weights:", tf.math.reduce_mean(scores, 1))
print("Torch Attendtion outputs:", transformer_encoder.self_attn(srcPT,srcPT,srcPT)[0])
print("Torch attention output weights:", transformer_encoder.self_attn(srcPT,srcPT,srcPT)[1])
```

and the result is:

```
Tensorflow Attendtion outputs: tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0.02602757 -0.14134401  0.00855263  0.4735083  -0.01851891
   -0.20382246 -0.18152176 -0.21076852  0.08623976 -0.33548725]
  [ 0.02607442 -0.1403394   0.00814065  0.47415024 -0.01882939
   -0.20353754 -0.18291879 -0.21234266  0.08595885 -0.33613583]
  [ 0.02524654 -0.14096384  0.00870436  0.47411725 -0.01800703
   -0.20486829 -0.18163288 -0.21082559  0.08571021 -0.3362339 ]
  [ 0.02518575 -0.14039244  0.0090138   0.47431853 -0.01775141
   -0.20391947 -0.18138805 -0.2118245   0.08432849 -0.33521986]
  [ 0.02556361 -0.14039293  0.00876258  0.4746476  -0.01891363
   -0.20398234 -0.18229616 -0.21147579  0.08555281 -0.33639923]]

 [[ 0.07844199 -0.1614371   0.01649148  0.5287745   0.05126739
   -0.13851154 -0.09829871 -0.1621251   0.01922669 -0.2428589 ]
  [ 0.07844222 -0.16024739  0.01805423  0.52941847  0.04975721
   -0.13537636 -0.09829231 -0.16129729  0.01979005 -0.24491176]
  [ 0.07800542 -0.160701    0.01677295  0.52902794  0.05082911
   -0.13843337 -0.09805533 -0.16165744  0.01928401 -0.24327613]
  [ 0.07815789 -0.1600025   0.01757433  0.5291927   0.05032986
   -0.1368022  -0.09849522 -0.16172451  0.01929555 -0.24438493]
  [ 0.0781548  -0.16028519  0.01764914  0.52846324  0.04941286
   -0.13746066 -0.09787872 -0.16141161  0.01994199 -0.2440269 ]]], shape=(2, 5, 10), dtype=float32)
Tensorflow (averaged) weights: tf.Tensor(
[[[0.199085   0.20275716 0.20086522 0.19873264 0.19856   ]
  [0.2015336  0.19960018 0.20218948 0.19891861 0.19775811]
  [0.19906266 0.20318432 0.20190334 0.19812575 0.19772394]
  [0.20074987 0.20104568 0.20269363 0.19744729 0.19806348]
  [0.19953248 0.20176074 0.20314851 0.19782843 0.19772986]]

 [[0.2010009  0.20053487 0.20004745 0.20092985 0.19748697]
  [0.20034568 0.20035927 0.19955876 0.20062163 0.19911464]
  [0.19967113 0.2006859  0.20012529 0.20047483 0.19904283]
  [0.20132652 0.19996871 0.20019794 0.20008174 0.19842513]
  [0.2006393  0.20000939 0.19938737 0.20054278 0.19942114]]], shape=(2, 5, 5), dtype=float32)
Torch Attendtion outputs: tensor([[[ 0.1097, -0.4467, -0.0719, -0.1779, -0.0766, -0.1247,  0.1557,
           0.0051, -0.3932, -0.1323],
         [ 0.1264, -0.3822,  0.0759, -0.0335, -0.1084, -0.1539,  0.1475,
          -0.0272, -0.4235, -0.1744]],

        [[ 0.1122, -0.4502, -0.0747, -0.1796, -0.0756, -0.1271,  0.1581,
           0.0049, -0.3964, -0.1340],
         [ 0.1274, -0.3823,  0.0754, -0.0356, -0.1091, -0.1547,  0.1477,
          -0.0272, -0.4252, -0.1752]],

        [[ 0.1089, -0.4427, -0.0728, -0.1746, -0.0756, -0.1202,  0.1501,
           0.0031, -0.3894, -0.1242],
         [ 0.1263, -0.3820,  0.0718, -0.0374, -0.1063, -0.1562,  0.1485,
          -0.0271, -0.4233, -0.1761]],

        [[ 0.1061, -0.4369, -0.0685, -0.1696, -0.0772, -0.1173,  0.1454,
           0.0012, -0.3860, -0.1201],
         [ 0.1265, -0.3820,  0.0762, -0.0325, -0.1082, -0.1560,  0.1501,
          -0.0271, -0.4249, -0.1779]],

        [[ 0.1043, -0.4402, -0.0705, -0.1719, -0.0791, -0.1205,  0.1508,
           0.0018, -0.3895, -0.1262],
         [ 0.1260, -0.3805,  0.0775, -0.0298, -0.1083, -0.1547,  0.1494,
          -0.0276, -0.4242, -0.1768]]], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
Torch attention output weights: tensor([[[0.2082, 0.2054, 0.1877, 0.1956, 0.2031],
         [0.2100, 0.2079, 0.1841, 0.1943, 0.2037],
         [0.2007, 0.1995, 0.1929, 0.1999, 0.2070],
         [0.1995, 0.1950, 0.1976, 0.2002, 0.2077],
         [0.1989, 0.1969, 0.1970, 0.2024, 0.2048]],

        [[0.2095, 0.1902, 0.1987, 0.2027, 0.1989],
         [0.2090, 0.1956, 0.1997, 0.2004, 0.1952],
         [0.2047, 0.1869, 0.2006, 0.2121, 0.1957],
         [0.2073, 0.1953, 0.1982, 0.2014, 0.1978],
         [0.2089, 0.2003, 0.1953, 0.1957, 0.1998]]], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
```

The output weights look similar but the base attention outputs are way off. Is there any way to make the Tensorflow model come out more like the Pytorch one? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MultiHeadAttention there is also a projection layer, like

```
Q = W_q @ input_query + b_q
K = W_k @ input_keys + b_k
V = W_v @ input_values + b_v
```

Matrices `W_q`, `W_k` and `W_v` and biases `b_q`, `b_k`, `b_v` are initialized randomly, so difference in outputs should be expected (even between outputs of two distinct layers in pytorch on same input). After self-attention operation there is one more projection and it's also initialized randomly. Weights can be set manually in tensorflow by calling method `set_weights` of `self_attnTF`.

Correspondence between weights in `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` and `nn.MultiheadAttention` not so clear, as an example: torch shares weights between heads, while tf keeps them unique. So if you are using weights of pretrained model from pytorch and try to put them in tensorflow model (for whatever reason) it'll certainly take more than five minutes.

Results should be the same if after initializing pytorch model and tensorflow model you step through their parameters and assign them identical values.

Comment: Sounds like getting the weights to be the same may not be as feasible as I thought based on what you're saying. Would you still expect that the pytorch and tensorflow models would act in generally the same way, even despite the differences in attention outputs? I'm using this for a classifier and I'm worried about how much of a difference the different attention outputs are going to make...

Comment: If you training weights and architectures same at the end it'lll still output high accuracy. And again even if you train 2 pytorch models initialized from different seeds outputs will also be distinct. So if you don't worry mismatch in "pytorch / pytorch" case than why should you worry about "pytorch / tensorflow"?

Comment: I'm not finished with recreating this model yet so I'm trying to determine if what I'm doing *will* work at all, so I don't actually know the final accuracy of what my tensorflow model would be. Based on what I've read here it seems like that difference would be too significant for it to work the same way and I'm going to have to find a new approach. 
Thank you for your help!